# WP_Query For Custom Author and Single CPT Search?

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type

I have created a search page where users can search the site with these options:

(1) Keyword
(2) Keyword in/from 12 different Custom Post Types (CPT's)
(3) Keyword in/by a single Author's posts across all CPT's
(4) Keyword in/across all Categories

But I need one more search option that I am missing, and which is very important to me:

(5) Author + CPT, where a user can select any Author and any single CPT from among the 12.

For example, if Jane is an Author and she has CPT posts in Audio, Video, or Blogs, etc., I need a user to be able to  search for all Jane's Video, where the search results only display the CPT Video and no other, by Jane.

I have seen other similar, but ultimately different questions, about how to display all CPT's by an Author. But I already have this. Now I need to add the narrower option of searching for one Author and one CPT.

My research leads me to believe that I would have to write a custom WP_Query to alter my search parameters. Is this correct? If so, does anyone have tips for how to do so? I have not written one before, I have read the Codex on it, but this is pushing me into new territory and is a bit over my head -- if I am even on the right track.

Thank you.

Comment: make a query like this ..
 myresult = $wpdb=>get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_author` = 'id_of_author' AND `post_status` = 'publish' AND `post_type` = 'mypost-type'", ARRAY_A);

Comment: Would I put this in my function.php file? If so do I need to add a filter or anything? Thank you. Can't wait to try...

Comment: wherever is ur other search logic exist, you can put it too.